# Python multiprocessing - problem manipulating data in a multiprocessing Array shared between parent and spawned class

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to implement a way to share a table of information between a parent function and the instances of classes it will be spawning. According to what I read, I need to use a table of `ctypes.c_char_p` of a given length.

I have managed to initialize that table from the parent function, that then I pass to the called class. from the `__init__()` of the class I can access its contents. Finally, I try to manipulate them (reverse the name in this example), I confirm - from the class - that the shared array is populated as expected, but when I try to view the contents from the parent process, I get garbage.

My code is below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import random
import json

class employee(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, employee_data, shared_array_fields):

        self.employee_data = employee_data
        self.shared_array_fields = shared_array_fields
        # self.lock = lock
        
        print("**" * 100)
        print("IN class:\n", employee_data[:])

        self.run()

    def run(self):
        for ii in range(self.shared_array_fields):
            employee_string = self.employee_data[ii].decode("utf-8")
            new_name_json = json.loads(employee_string)
            new_name = new_name_json["name"][::-1]
            self.employee_data[ii] = bytes('{ "name": "' + str(new_name) + '" }', "utf-8")

        print("**" * 100)
        print("IN class AFTER manipulation:\n", self.employee_data[:])


shared_array_fields = 5

def main():
    global shared_array_fields

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    employee_data = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_char_p, shared_array_fields)

    for ii in range(shared_array_fields):
        name = ''.join(random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) for i in range(10)) + "_" + str(ii)
        employee_data[ii] = bytes('{ "name": "' + str(name) + '" }', "utf-8")

    print("**" * 100)
    print("BEFORE class:\n", employee_data[:])

    proc1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=employee, args=(employee_data, shared_array_fields))
    proc1.start()
    proc1.join()

    # time.sleep(1)

    print("**" * 100)
    print("AFTER class:\n", employee_data[:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-32 tmp]$ ./temp.py 
********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
BEFORE class:
 [b'{ "name": "abbbabeadc_0" }', b'{ "name": "daeebeeabc_1" }', b'{ "name": "dbbceedece_2" }', b'{ "name": "caccdcbeae_3" }', b'{ "name": "ccdcbdabdb_4" }']
********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
IN class:
 [b'{ "name": "abbbabeadc_0" }', b'{ "name": "daeebeeabc_1" }', b'{ "name": "dbbceedece_2" }', b'{ "name": "caccdcbeae_3" }', b'{ "name": "ccdcbdabdb_4" }']
********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
IN class AFTER manipulation:
 [b'{ "name": "0_cdaebabbba" }', b'{ "name": "1_cbaeebeead" }', b'{ "name": "2_ecedeecbbd" }', b'{ "name": "3_eaebcdccac" }', b'{ "name": "4_bdbadbcdcc" }']
********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
AFTER class:
 [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'{ "name": "daeebeeabc_1" }']
[http_offline@greenhat-32 tmp]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an Array is very cumbersome since it is very difficult to rewrite a whole new value to it. Also why go through the necessity of converting from a dictionary to a string and back just to use an Array? Finally, any structure you wish to share between processes should be created by an a "manager" instance created by a call to `multiprocessing.Manager()` *unless you want to manage the synchronization yourself*.

The easiest way to accomplish your goal is to have the manager create two Queue objects, an input queue (for the input to your process) and an output queue to hold the result. In this particular case you could use the same queue object for both, but this is cleaner and is generally what you would use when you had multiple inputs and outputs being processed simultaneously by a pool of processes *and you weren't using a standard library module such as `multiprocessing.pool` or `concurrent.futures`*.

Finally, your construction of your `Process` subclass requires a bit of tweaking (your constructor need to call the base class constructor and should not call `run`). It's also usual to name your classes with a capital letter, although I left the name unchanged. I also think it's more usual not to subclass `Process`. Generally one just writes a function and passes to the call to `Process` `target`, `args` and/or `kwargs` parameters.

**Update to Use a Managed Dictionary**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import random

class employee(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, employees):

        super().__init__()   # init the base class !!!
        self.employees = employees

        print("**" * 100)
        print("IN class:\n", self.employees[:])


    def run(self):
        employees = self.employees
        for i, employee in enumerate(employees):
            new_name = employee["name"][::-1]
            employee["name"] = new_name
            employees[i] = employee # must be rewritten to show it has changed. Yuck!
        #self.employees = employees

        print("**" * 100)
        print("IN class AFTER manipulation:\n", employees[:])


def main():

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    employees = manager.list()

    for ii in range(5):
        name = ''.join(random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) for i in range(10)) + "_" + str(ii)
        employees.append({"name": name})

    print("**" * 100)
    print("BEFORE class:\n", employees[:])

    proc1 = employee(employees)
    proc1.start()
    proc1.join()

    # time.sleep(1)

    print("**" * 100)
    print("AFTER class:\n", employees[:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: many thanks for all the recommendations, i was trying to avoid the queues as it adds more complexity than just having one structured array shared around the parent and multiple child processes, but as i am completely stuck i will give queues a try. i will play around after work and revert.

Comment: I believe the Queue greatly simplifies the solution.

Comment: well, i think one array that each spawned process would be modifying its own dictionary of necessary information and this array is automatically reflected in real time to both the parent and other child processes would be easier that having 2 queues (per child process) that you need to be polling constantly for new messages, but since i cant figure out what i am doing wrong (and all examples i found around are for spawning functions as processes, not whole classes ) i will try your approach.

Comment: First, the easiest way to initialize an array of (Unicode) characters is `employee_data = multiprocessing.Array('u', '{"name": "John Doe"}')` and not full around with bytes at all. But updating still remains a problem. In your simple, artificial case you are reversing a name so you are neither shortening nor lengthening the response so you can update the characters in place (you still have to do it character by character). But what if the result is shorter or longer? Trying to provide a response by updating the input is a poor approach.

Comment: I've updated the answer with something that I think you will like, which is to use a manged list (which requires no explicitly locking if multiple processes were accessing it concurrently) in place of your `multiprocessing.Array`, which had been used to hold a JSON representation of a list (of dictionaries).

Comment: Also reread my intro; I have clarified a few points.

Comment: wow, this definitely nailed it! although i had read about this list, from the articles/posts i found, i got convinced that the Array is the proper way to go, and completely overlooked this option. Seems this approach can cover my need of sharing dicts across the processes (actualy the idea is each process will be modifying one dict element in the list, and the parent process can see the dicts from all processes). Although i was psychologically ready to try a queue solution, i think the queues will have to wait for another "project" :) Many many thanks for your help!